# Hibernate transform instance to subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm, jpa

I have mapped class in JPA. :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private Long name;
    //getters and setters go here
    ....
}
```

I also have a subclass of this class, called Admin:

```
@Entity
public class Admin extends User {
    private String cridentials;
    //getters and setters go here
    ....
}
```

Now in my code I have managed instance of User attached to the session

```
...
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId)
```

I need to transform this user to its subclass, Admin. This means I need 'User' table data remain untouched and new row to be inserted into 'Admin' table:

```
javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager = ...;
...
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId)
Admin admin = new Admin();
admin.setName(user.getName());

entityManager.persist(admin);
```

But after I execute the last line, another row is inserted in both User and Admin tables.  How would I solve this?

The only way I found so far is to save the fields of a User somewhere, then delete this instance from DB, and then create new Admin with all the data from User class. But I bet there is much better way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) But after I execute the last line, another row is inserted in both User and Admin tables. How would I solve this?

Well, you created a new instance of `Admin` and called `persist` on it so this is exactly what you told Hibernate to do. Try to downcast the fetched `User` instance as `Admin` instead (not tested).

But there is IMO something broken with your design, you should assign some kind of role instead of using inheritance here.

Comment: Actually, Admin has many properties that User shouldn't have - that's why I use inheritance. User can't be downcasted to Admin, so 
'Admin a = (Admin) user;'
doesn't work here... The problem  that User is not abstract, it is used by the system as well as Admin. However, I can't 'tell' hibernate to create new Admin from current User - even when I set Admin's ID to User's one and try to merge, it say that Admin is not managed.